# Why is this `if` block not executed

Tags: python

The below piece of code intends to ask for a desired username and then to create it.

I want to tell the user when the username has already been taken. That works.

However, whenever a username is input that does not yet exist, I want all of the `if a != 1:` block to be executed, but that does not happen. Why is that?

Here is a snippet of the code that I've narrowed down to where the problem occurs:

```
UsernameRequest = input("What would you like your username to be set? ")
fname = UsernameRequest + ".txt"
try:
    f2 = open(fname, 'r')
    a = f2.readline(1)
    if a == "a":
        print ("This username is already taken!")
        f2.close()
        a = 1
except:
    b = 1

if a != 1:
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    PasswordRequest = input("What would you like your password to be? ")
    f.write("abcde" + '\n')
    f.write(UsernameRequest)
    f.write('\n' + PasswordRequest)
    f.close()
    print ("User created! Welcome to SterlOS!")
    Login()
    break
```

Comment: I have never seen a program starting with `elif` before.

Comment: do `a=0` before the try

Comment: There are easier ways to keep a persistent record of taken usernames than making a text file for each one containing the letter "a". For serilialization, Consider using `pickle` or `json` or `shelve` or a full-blown database.

Comment: @Eugene -- That is Py's `else if` --  The OP said he'd narrowed the problem down to this "snippet" of code ..

Comment: @Zak I know. But the OP is claiming "this code is not working properly". Well, it cannot.

Comment: Well, maybe `a` is set to 1? As it is, the code you've posted should throw a NameError in `if a != 1`.

Comment: This is clearly not reproducible, I think that's @EugeneSh. main point

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I rearranged your question a bit, so it is easier to digest. To avoid confusion I also removed the `elif` line, as it is not relevant and only confuses people. The question that you should answer yourself is: what is the value of `a` at the start of this code and just before `if a != 1`. This is part of the debugging you should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the scope of the variable `a` is the problem here. Try declaring `a` outside of the try block.